# H3 is automatically 100% width in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Hi I have created an `h3` which is centered and uses a `background-image` and `padding`. It appears fine in all browsers (i.e. the `h3` is the width of the text within it, plus the padding) except IE7, where the `h3` seems to default to 100% width. I don't want to set a static width as I need it to resize depending on the text. Any ideas? Here is the site:

- http://www.firecrestmoto.co.uk/index.php (it's the "Our Latest Arrivals" text)

```css
h3.bannerh3 {
    font-family: "alternate-gothic-no-1-d",sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 64px;
    height: 78px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000000;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=0, offy=0);
    background: url('../../../../img/h2top3.png') repeat-x top, url('../../../../img/h2bottom3.png')  repeat-x bottom;
    -pie-background: url('/img/h2top3.png') repeat-x top, url('/img/h2bottom3.png')  repeat-x bottom; /*PIE*/
    behavior: url(js/pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `inline-block` in IE7. Try the following instead:

```
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

The second `display` property will be interpreted by IE7, and will set the element to `inline`. Unfortunately this will prevent you from having the style exactly as you'd like it in IE7 since `inline` and `inline-block` aren't identical.

If further styling is desired, conditional comments may be more appropriate:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        h3.bannerh3 {
          display: inline;
          /* Additional styles here */
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```